# Python: OpenMPI Vs. RabbitMQ

Tags: python, messaging, mpi, rabbitmq, amqp

Suppose that one is interested to write a `python` app where there should be communication between different processes. The communications will be done by sending `strings` and/or `numpy` arrays.

What are the considerations to prefer `OpenMPI` vs. a tool like `RabbitMQ`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no single correct answer to such question. It all depends on a big number of different factors. For example:

1. What kind of communications do you have? Are you sending large packets or small packets, do you need good bandwidth or low latency?
2. What kind of delivery guarantees do you need?
3. OpenMPI can instantly deliver messages only to a running process, while different MQ solutions can queue messages and allow fancy producer-consumer configurations.
4. What kind of network do you have? If you are running on the localhost, something like `ZeroMQ` would probably be the fastest. If you are running on the set of hosts, depends on the interconnections available. E.g. OpenMPI can utilize infiniband/mirynet links.
5. What kind of processing are you doing? With MPI all processes are usually started at the same time, do the processing and terminate all at once.

Comment: abbot, thank you for your response. Yes, I am sending `large packets` (few MBs each) across a network of 100 machines; I have a simple, 1G network. Nothing fancy; can have a little latency -- doesn't have to be the fastest.

Comment: +1.  In general, MPI is good for running a single large task on multiple reliable nodes (eg, nodes in a cluster, or a bunch of PCs in a lab).   As mentioned above, it's also great when you don't know what sort of networking have, or you want to take advantage of shared memory between cores on a node.   The further you stray from this sort of use case, the less well MPI fits.   I'll just add that OpenMPI is just one implementation of MPI; MPICH2, another, is just as good.  And if you are going to use MPI+Python, I recommend mpi4py. ( http://mpi4py.scipy.org/ )

Comment: Jonathan, thank you. Are there any pluses for using `OpenMPI` vs. `RabbitMQ`?

Comment: Of course there are. And it all depends on the answers to the questions in my reply. For example: OpenMPI would tear RabbitMQ to pieces in terms of throughput and latency if it is running on a cluster with Infiniband hardware. RabbitMQ does allow easy configurations like several producers - several consumers, while you will have to write a lot of boilerplate to do this with OpenMPI. Etc, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly the scenario I was in a few months ago and I decided to use AMQP with RabbitMQ using topic exchanges, in addition to memcache for large objects.

The AMQP messages are all strings, in JSON object format so that it is easy to add attributes to a message (like number of retries) and republish it. JSON objects are a subset of JSON that correspond to Python dicts. For instance {"recordid": "272727"} is a JSON object with one attribute. I could have just pickled a Python dict but that would have locked us into only using Python with the message queues.

The large objects don't get routed by AMQP, instead they go into a memcache where they are available for another process to retrieve them. You could just as well use Redis or Tokyo Tyrant for this job. The idea is that we did not want short messages to get queued behind large objects.

In the end, my Python processes ended up using both AMQP and ZeroMQ for two different aspects of the architecture. You may find that it makes sense to use both OpenMPI  and AMQP but for different types of jobs.

In my case, a supervisor process runs forever, starts a whole flock of worker who also run forever unless they die or hang, in which case the supervisor restarts them. The work constantly flows in as messages via AMQP, and each process handles just one step of the work, so that when we identify a bottleneck we can have multiple instances of the process, possibly on separate machines, to remove the bottleneck. In my case, I have 15 instances of one process, 4 of two others, and about 8 other single instances.

Comment: Michael, this is an interesting design. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: you should also consider _[msgpack](http://msgpack.org/)_ for serialization, it works very well with _zeromq_.